# Pegar Strings de outras Activitys

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Como faço para pegar uma String, ou mais, de uma outra Activity, e depois usa-la em outra Activity, alguém aí sabe me dizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para transferir informações entre activities deve usar o proprio `Intent`, que tem vários métodos para adicionar e obter informação.

Para adicionar informação deve usar o método `putExtra`, que tem vários *overloads* sendo um deles precisamente para `String`. Quando o usa tem de associar um nome à `String` que está a enviar:

**Activity1.java**:

```
String minhaString = "algum texto nesta String";

Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class); //Activity1 abre a Activity2
i.putExtra("nomeAssociado", minhaString); //colocar a String na informação a enviar
startActivity(i); //abrir a Activity2
```

Para obter a informação guardada utilize o método `getStringExtra` na Activity que foi aberta e dentro do método `onCreate`.

**Activity2.java**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meu_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent(); //obter o Intent enviado

    //apanhar a String enviada da Activity1 com base no nome associado
    String stringDaActivity1 = intent.getStringExtra("nomeAssociado");
```

Se o nome com que se baseia para ir buscar a `String` não estiver correto, ou o extra não existir, irá obter `null`,e por isso deve testar se conseguiu obter o valor pretendido antes de o utilizar.

Documentação para a [classe Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), para o [`putExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), e [`getExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String))